# Regex, grouping constant strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using a regex just like this:

```
/o?n?e?t?w?o?t?h?r?e?e?/
```

Is there a way to do it like:

```
/(one)?(two)?(three)?/   // it doesn't work
```

I'm tring to replace the words "one", "two" and "three" with a single regex.

Comment: Sure you can do it that way, but it might not result in what you want. Unfortunately you have not explained what you want, so we cannot really help you.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why don't you like your first approach and why are you trying to change it to the second approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To replace either "one", "two" or "three" with the same word, use a RegExp, separated by a pipe. Also add the `g` flag for a global search-and replace.

Example:

```
var string = "one fellow, two hands, three legs";
string = string.replace(/(one|two|three)/g, "--$1--");
alert(string); //--one-- fellow, --two-- hands, --three-- legs
```

Comment: Edit your answer, and add input + expected output. My RegEx satisfied the requirements in your current question.

Comment: @Rckt: And what exactly does not work? @Rob: You should also add the `i` modifier.

Comment: The `i` flag should only be added if case-insensitivity is desired.

Comment: Perhaps also use word boundary anchors `\b(one|two|three)\b` to avoid submatches in words like `lonely`.